# append values to data frame r for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, append

I am trying to perform a fairly basic operation in R which is giving me some trouble.

I have a for loop with 100 iterations which creates a data frame with 7 observations in each iteration. I would like to somehow append the results of each iteration to the end of the previous iteration. So, after the final iteration the result would be a data frame with 700 observations.

```
for(k in 1:100){

X = runif(200,-3,3)
X2 = X^2

e.1 = rnorm(200,0,0.2^2)
y.1 = cos(X)^2 + e.1
fit.1 = lm(y.1 ~ X + X2)

X.val.1=-3:3
X.val.2=X.val.1^2

mat.k=data.frame(rep(0,7), rep(0,7), rep(0,7))
true_val.k=rep(0,7)
diff.k=rep(0,7)

names(mat.k)[1]=paste("fitted value")
names(mat.k)[2]=paste("lower bound")
names(mat.k)[3]=paste("upper bound")

for(i in 1:7){
    mat.k[i,]=predict(fit.1,data.frame(X=X[i],X2=X2[i]),interval="confidence")
    true_val.k[i]=cos(X[i])^2+rnorm(1,0,0.2^2)
    diff.k[i]=true_val.k[i]-mat.k[i,1]
    }

mat.full.k=data.frame(X.val.1,true_val.k,diff.k,mat.k,(true_val.1 < mat.k[,3] & true_val.k > mat.k[,2])*1)
names(mat.full.k)[1]=paste("X")
names(mat.full.k)[2]=paste("true value")
names(mat.full.k)[3]=paste("difference")
names(mat.full.k)[7]=paste("cover")
}
```

I initially thought I could create 100 separate data frames (mat.full.1, mat.full.2, mat.full.3,...) and then combine them together using another for loop, but R returns an error stating that object 'mat.full.1' not found. The only data frame it can find is mat.full.k.

I would like to return a data frame like the one below but with 700 observations, not just the last 7.

```
> mat.full.k
   X true value  difference fitted.value lower.bound upper.bound cover
1 -3 0.40681014 -0.04118873    0.4479989   0.3834096   0.5125881     1
2 -2 1.01834958  0.58296771    0.4353819   0.3649005   0.5058633     1
3 -1 0.98116822  0.54585026    0.4353180   0.3647855   0.5058504     1
4  0 0.12059332 -0.38227681    0.5028701   0.4241385   0.5816018     0
5  1 0.97424142  0.39806096    0.5761805   0.4505279   0.7018330     0
6  2 0.04907813 -0.43703754    0.4861157   0.4226798   0.5495515     0
7  3 0.41136178 -0.10964164    0.5210034   0.4399401   0.6020667     0
```

I have searched through a few forums and have tried using the list() function but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: One thing that you'd want to consider is that when you loop from 1 to 100 using k as iterator, "mat.k <-  data.frame(...)" won't result in an object called mat.1, mat.2 or mat.3 but simply in an object called mat.k.

Comment: your code is producing an error: `Error in data.frame(X.val.1, true_val.k, diff.k, mat.k, (true_val.1 <  : 
  object 'true_val.1' not found`

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
oneDF <- function() {
X = runif(200,-3,3)
X2 = X^2

e.1 = rnorm(200,0,0.2^2)
y.1 = cos(X)^2 + e.1
fit.1 = lm(y.1 ~ X + X2)

X.val.1=-3:3
X.val.2=X.val.1^2

mat.k=data.frame(rep(0,7), rep(0,7), rep(0,7))
true_val.k=rep(0,7)
diff.k=rep(0,7)

names(mat.k)[1]=paste("fitted value")
names(mat.k)[2]=paste("lower bound")
names(mat.k)[3]=paste("upper bound")

for(i in 1:7){
    mat.k[i,]=predict(fit.1,data.frame(X=X[i],X2=X2[i]),interval="confidence")
    true_val.k[i]=cos(X[i])^2+rnorm(1,0,0.2^2)
    diff.k[i]=true_val.k[i]-mat.k[i,1]
    }

mat.full.k=data.frame(X.val.1,true_val.k,diff.k,mat.k,(true_val.1 < mat.k[,3] & true_val.k > mat.k[,2])*1)
names(mat.full.k)[1]=paste("X")
names(mat.full.k)[2]=paste("true value")
names(mat.full.k)[3]=paste("difference")
names(mat.full.k)[7]=paste("cover")
mat.full.k
}
fullDF <- oneDF()
for (k in 2:100) fullDF <- rbind(fullDF, oneDF())
```

There is a lot to optimize in that code. For now I simply take yours.
HTH

p.s.:
while your code for constructing one dataframe is producing an error, take my code as example, i.e. a function to return one dataframe and then the loop at the end of my code.